# How can I sort an ArrayList?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` of multiple instances of the class `ElementClass`. Inside the `ElementClass` is a method named `getCounter()` that returns the value of the variable `counter` inside that class. This variable can only have `0`, `1`, or `2` as its values.

I need to sort these `ArrayList` entries in ascending order depending on the value that the method `getCounter()` returns. How can I accomplish that? I tried to research several methods but all those that I have found requires setting a value. For example:

`list[i + 1] = temp`

But `ArrayList`s do not allow setting a value. For example:

```
ArrayList<ElementClass> temp = list.get(i);
list.get(i + 1) = temp;
```

The above code would not allow me to compile because of errors. `ArrayList`s only allow adding of items at the end of the list (through the `.add(item)` method) and removing an item from a specific index (through the `.remove(index)` method.)

How can I accomplish the sorting using only the `add()` and `remove()` methods? Or is there another way to sort ArrayLists in Java?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<ElementClass>() {
   public int compare(ElementClass a, ElementClass b){
      return a.getCounter()-b.getCounter();
   }
});
```

Comment: Maybe that is descending (have not tested it). If you need it the other way around, switch a and b in the subtraction.

Comment: In this piece of code, is `list` the `ArrayList` I need to sort?

Comment: In Java 8, this will hopefully become the more compact `Collections.sort(list, (ElementClass a, ElementClass b) -> a.getCounter()-b.getCounter())`

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't seem to work. It gives me errors whenever I type it in. I think I'm placing it on the wrong place. I'm placing it under a method called `sortListByCounter()`. Should I not do it that way? Should I place this on the part where I need to sort the ArrayList and not inside a method?

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice the code was edited. I have slow internet so I didn't see it immediately. It's working fine now. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Not slow internet, something about how Stackexchange load-balances and caches. Seems to have gotten much worse a few weeks back.

Answer (score 3):

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<ElementClass> {
    @Override
    public int compare(ElementClass o1, ElementClass o2) {
        if (o1.getCounter() == o2.getCounter()) {
            return 0;
        }
        return o1.getCounter() < o2.getCounter() ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

if `getCounter` uses wrapper class (like `Integer` instead of `int`), you can do:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<ElementClass> {
    @Override
    public int compare(ElementClass o1, ElementClass o2) {
        return (o1.getCounter().compareTo(o2.getCounter());
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of returning int should I return Integer. Is that what you mean for the second snippet of code?

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();

        list.add(new A(5));
        list.add(new A(3));
        list.add(new A(1));
        list.add(new A(8));

        Comparator<A> comp = new Comparator<A>() {
           public int compare(A a, A b){
              return a.getField()-b.getField();
           }
        };

        Collections.sort(list, comp);
        for(A a:list){
            System.out.println("Field value : "+a.getField());
        }
```

OUTPUT:

```
Field value : 1
Field value : 3
Field value : 5
Field value : 8
```